# Не могу понять как работает добавление данных в список

Tags: python, python-3.x

Есть простой код

```
a = []
for i in range(int(input())):
    a.append(int(input()))
    print(a)
```

Смысл в том, чтобы вводить числа и добавлять их в список, нужно чтобы каждую цифру я вводил с новой строки.
В итоге данные  добавляются в список только со второго значения, вот пример из консоли:

```
..10
..10
[10]
..10
[10, 10]
..10
[10, 10, 10]
```

Comment: Так должно быть понятнее: `a=[int(input('Сколько? ')) for _ in range(int(input('> ')))]` =)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = [] 
while True:
    input_ = input()
    if input_ == 'готово':
        break
    a.append(int(input_)) 
    print(a)
```

Comment: благодарю :) то что надо

Answer (score 1):

```
a = []
b = int(input('Сколько чисел хочешь ввести?'))
for i in range(b):
    a.append(int(input('Введи число')))
    print(a)
```

Я бы сделал это так. Вы в своем коде просите ввод данных в функцию range,то-есть вы сначала спрашиваете у пользователя сколько чисел будет внесено в список,и только потом вносите эти числа.

Comment: там дальше суть будет в том, чтобы все это заканчивалось послве ввода "готово" и проводились некоторые действия

Comment: @Кирилл вы добавляете в список значения типа `int`, о каком `готово` вы говорите?

Comment: @Varikk `a.append(int(input(f'Введите {i+1} число: ')))` ?